# Tables and subtables relation in Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sqlite

I have a all users table and the users can be of type admin, coordinator or member.
I need another table admin which needs to look at the all users table and check for which users admin==true. If it is true it is in the admin table with other fields unique to admins.
How would I do this using Active Record?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need another table.  You can easily get all the admin users with something like this:

admins = User.where(:admin => true)

This will give you an ActiveRecord::Relation which should suffice instead of actually another table.